# install Ubuntu on a Mac book single boot

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, mac

I have a Mac Book (2006)

- 2 gb ram
- 2.2 GHz processor core 2 duo (intel-based processor)
- 80 GB hdd
- loaded with Windows 7 x86 only (single boot) - I've deleted the Mac X OS completely before and I don't have any Mac OS DVDs right now

So here's what I want to do:

- I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 on my Mac as a single boot (and get rid of windows 7)
  How exactly can I do that??
- And How can I also dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 on this Mac? (in case I want to in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Ubuntu on your computer you'll either need an external hard drive or an Ubuntu DVD/CD. Then you simply pop the CD in, and hold Option down at boot. This will give you a list of available boot devices. Select your CD, and you are set! (Don't fully partition your hard drive for Ubuntu if you want a Windows install later on, but be warned Windows 7 takes about 20GB of space, and on 80GB that is 1/4th of your hard drive!)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook - Info on your specific macbook (I couldn't find a 2006 macbook with your specs)

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows - Burning an Ubuntu disk on Windows

Comment: can I install Ubuntu on the same partition Windows is installed on?(suppose there's enough empty space for both Ubuntu and Windows on the same partition)
Note that my hdd is formatted as follows: 
one 25 GB partition with Windows installed on it
the other 55 GB partition (data)

Comment: No, you'll need to create a new partition for Ubuntu. It should however be able to share the data partition :)

Comment: What about if I installed Ubuntu via wubi, wouldn't I still be able to install Ubuntu on the same partition windows is installed on?

Comment: Yes you could, but Wubi is no longer supported, and it is limited to about 20GB I believe. It was intended (in my opinion) to be an Ubuntu trial, not a full fledged installation.

Comment: @rockon999 Is there a way to do this with a USB?